# Why duplicates content in class?

Tags: php, class, oop

I wrote a some classes for prepare information and send it to parent class for get teplate:

**Description:**

```
// Parent class
class FeedTemplate {

  public    $data = array();
    function __construct($data = array()){}

    function getTemplate(){
       return $this->CI->load->view('socialfeed/template', $this->data, true);
    }
}

class ArticleTemplate extends FeedTemplate {

}

class VideoTemplate extends FeedTemplate {
     function __construct($data = array()){
         parent::__construct($data);
     }

     function getTemplate(){
         $this->data['media'] = $this->CI->load->view('video/video_single', $this->data, true);
         parent::getTemplate();
     }
}
```

**Create objects:**

```
...
case 'article':
     $obj = new ArticleTemplate($value);
     $this->template.= $obj->getTemplate();
break;


case 'video':
      $video = new VideoTemplate($value);
      $this->template.= $video->getTemplate();
break;
...
```

View **socialfeed/template**:

```
<div class="text"><?=$media?><?=$content['text']?></div>
```

So, problem is after created object `$VideoTemplate` and getting template for Video, for a next object - `ArticleTemplate` I get template content with a previos template video plus content current object. It is a difficult to explain

Extended code:

```
    class FeedTemplate {

        public    $data = array();
        protected $inputdata = array();
        public    $width_content = 500;
        private   $category;
        protected $CI;

        function __construct($data = array()){

            $this->inputdata = $data;
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->data['user'] = $this->getUserInfo($this->inputdata->user);

            /* Load Libraries */
            $this->CI->load->library('translate');
        }

        protected function getCategory($url){

            if(!empty($this->inputdata->categoryPrivate)){
                return ', <a target="_blank" href="'.$url.'">'.$this->inputdata->categoryPrivate.'</a>';

            } else if(!empty($this->inputdata->categoryPublic)) {

                $this->CI->load->library('listdata');
                $this->category['id']   = $this->CI->listdata->specializationList[$this->inputdata->categoryPublic]['idSpecialization'];
                $this->category['name'] = $this->CI->listdata->specializationList[$this->inputdata->categoryPublic]['SpecializationName'];
                return ', <a target="_blank" href="'.$url.$this->category['id'].'">'.$this->category['name'].'</a>';
            }
        }

        protected function getUserInfo($data){
            $user = new InformationUser($data);
            return $user->getUser();
        }

        function getHash($id, $type){
            return $this->hash = HashDataView(array('id' => $id, 'type' => $type));
        }

        function getTemplate(){
            return $this->CI->load->view('socialfeed/template_post', $this->data, true);

        }
    }



class ArticleTemplate extends FeedTemplate {

    public $category;
    public $photo;
    public $width  = 495;
    public $height = '';

    function __construct($data = array()){
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->data['content']['title'] = $data->ArticleName;
        $this->data['content']['time']  = $data->ArticleTime;
        $this->data['content']['text']  = $data->ArticleDescription;
        $this->data['content']['url_post'] = '/articles/'.$data->id;
        $this->data['content']['category'] = 'Articles';
        $this->data['content']['category_url'] = 'articles';
        $this->data['content']['id'] = $data->id;
    }

    function getImage(){
            $number = count($this->photo);
            if ($number > 0){
                $images = '';
                $this->getResizeImage($number);

                foreach($this->photo as $key => $value){
                    $img['title'] = $key;
                    $img['src']   = $value;
                    $img['width'] = $this->width;
                    $img['height'] = $this->height;
                    $images.= $this->getImageHTML($img);
                }

                return '<div class="photo">'.$images.'</div>';
            }
    }

    function getImageData($src, $type){
        switch($type){
            case 'width':
                return imagesx($src);
            case 'height':
                return imagesy($src);
        }
    }

    function getResizeImage($number){
        switch($number){
            case 2:
                $this->width  = $this->width_content / $number - 5;
                $this->height = 160; 
                break;
            case 3:
                foreach($this->photo as $key => $value){
                    $this->photo[$key] = $this->getImageData($value['src'], 'height');
                }
                asort($this->photo);
                break;
            case 4:
                $this->width = $this->width_content / 2;
                break;
        }
    }

    function getImageHTML($data = array()){
        return '<div style="width:'.$data['width'].'px; height:'.$data['height'].'px">
        <a href="'.$data['src'].'" class="fancybox"><img alt="'.$data['title'].'" title="'.$data['title'].'" width="'.$data['width'].'" src="'.$data['src'].'"></a></div>';
    }
}


class VideoTemplate extends FeedTemplate {

    public  $width;
    public  $height;
    public  $thumb;
    public  $code;
    public  $album;
    public  $hash;
    private $id;
    private $category;
    private $album_url;

    function __construct($data = array()){

        parent::__construct($data);

        $this->data['content']['title'] = $data->usersalbumsvideoTitle;
        $this->data['content']['time']  = $data->usersalbumsvideoTime;
        $this->data['content']['id']    = $data->id;

        $this->thumb      = $data->usersalbumsvideoThumb;
        $this->code       = $data->usersalbumsvideoCode;
        $this->album_url  = $this->getAlbumLink($data);
        $this->id         = $data->id;

        $this->height = 270;
        $this->width  = 400;
        $this->getVideo();
    }

    private function getAlbumLink($data){
        return '/wm'.$data->user['id'].'/video/albums/'.$data->albumID;
    }

    function getCategory(){
        $this->data['content']['category'] = 'Video';
        $this->data['content']['category_url'] = 'video';
        return parent::getCategory($this->album_url);
    }

    function getVideo(){
        $this->data['video']['id']         = $this->id;
        $this->data['video']['thumb']      = $this->thumb;
        $this->data['video']['code']       = $this->code;
        $this->data['video']['height']     = $this->height;
        $this->data['video']['width']      = $this->width;
        $this->data['content']['url_post'] = $this->album_url;
        $this->data['content']['sub_category'] = $this->getCategory();
        $this->data['video']['hash']       = parent::getHash($this->id, 6);
    }

    function getTemplate(){
        $this->data['media'] = $this->CI->load->view('video/video_single', $this->data, true);
        parent::getTemplate();
    }
}


Class InitTemplate {

    public $template;

    function __construct($data = array()){
        $this->init($data);
    }

    private function decodeJSON($value){
        return json_decode($value);
    }

    private function init($data){
        foreach($data['data'] as $value => $key){

            $value = $this->decodeJSON($value);
            $value->user = current($data['user']);

            switch($value->type){

                case 'article':
                    $obj = new ArticleTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $obj->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'video':
                    $video = new VideoTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $video->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'link':
                    $link = new LinkTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $link->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'comment':
                    break;

                case 'new':
                    $obj = new NewTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $obj->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'vacance':
                    break;

                case 'stock':
                    $obj = new StockTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $obj->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'photo':
                    break;

                case 'question':
                    $obj = new QuestionTemplate($value);
                    $this->template.= $obj->getTemplate();
                    break;

                case 'answer':
                    break;

                case 'albumphoto':
                    break;

                case 'videoalbum':
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    public function getTemplateVar(){
        return $this->template;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not difficult to explain as you have concatenation here `$this->template.= $video->getTemplate();` See that `.=`?

Comment: Yes, it is a correct. All result HTML a put in string. I tried var_dump($this->data) and see that $media exixts only in one array, it is a good, but dont understand why it is showed in any template

Comment: So what do you expect? If your `$this->template` already has some string, and you concatented it with another string - there are two strings in it.

Comment: Yes, for example there are a two posts, the first video and article. A get string template for video and get string from article. After combine them to commnon string, so get two post in one string. But I can not find a mistake, why the data from one object to another fall (template)

Comment: Is the `switch` within a loop ?

Comment: Still I can't understand your problem. Can you provide more code for a template? How do you output your objects?

Comment: Also, you can improve your code performance by removing the `switch` and use Factory pattern.
eg:
`$class = $video . 'Template';
$template = new $class($value);
$this->template = $template->getTemplate();`

Comment: Yes, switch in loop! Ok, now extend question with a full code

Comment: Somebody can help? Problem with a class Video and parent class

Comment: The idea is that the input of different types of information: articles, news, video. Depending on this, the information is transmitted particular class (Article, News. Video), which prepares the data `$ this-> data` and calls `getTemplate ()` of the parent class, whose task is to stuff these data on a template and return the template itself. All types of classes have one and the same parent `FeedTemplate`